# how to run that view inside of a django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new with Django, so please bear with me.

I have the following view

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(http_method_names=['POST'])
def login_agro_user(request):

    request_data = request.data

    if not request_data:
        return Response({"status_code": 400})

    secret = request_data.get('secret')
    if secret != 'test':
        return Response({"status_code": 400})

    payload = request_data.get('payload')
    payload = json.loads(base64.b64decode(payload).decode('utf-8'))
    serializer = AgroUserSerializer(data=payload)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        query = AgroUser.objects.filter(user_guid=payload['user_guid'])
        if not query:
            serializer.save()
        elif query[0].active == False:
            query.update(active=True)
        key = secrets.token_urlsafe()
        query.update(key=key)
        response_data = {"callback": f"{settings.FRONT_BASE_URL}/{key}"}
        return Response(response_data)

    return Response({"status_code": 400})
```

This view seems to be linked to the following endpoint

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/login_agro_user', login_agro_user),
```

The code should be generating a token, like this one `zLdu6NrHnvyUnixnvV-PiaQwro4QSNp0MaRmYQ9W09c`.

However,

My question are the following:

- Where should the view be appearing?
- If I want to create the token, should I run the views in a standalone mode?

Any help is welcomed as I'm losing my sanity.

Thanks.

Comment: You can call the view with a POST request to `localhost:3000/api/v1/login_agro_user` (or something else if you deployed it to a webserver). But it will not work, since you should use a `JsonResponse` here.

Comment: The standalone mode of Django is useful when you want to write a script, not anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the answer, but you can call your method like this:

```
curl -XPOST 0:8000/api/v1/login_agro_user -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"secret": "test", "payload": "eyJmaXJzdF9uYW1lIjogIkpvaG4iLCAibGFzdF9uYW1lIjogIkRvZSIsICJlbWFpbCI6ICJmb29AZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCAiYWN0aXZlIjogdHJ1ZSwgImtleSI6ICJzZWNyZXQifQ=="}'
```

To create a proper payload you may use:

```
>>> import base64
>>> import json
>>> base64.b64encode(json.dumps({"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "email": "foo@example.com", "active": True, "key": "secret"}).encode('utf8'))
b'eyJmaXJzdF9uYW1lIjogIkpvaG4iLCAibGFzdF9uYW1lIjogIkRvZSIsICJlbWFpbCI6ICJmb29AZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCAiYWN0aXZlIjogdHJ1ZSwgImtleSI6ICJzZWNyZXQifQ=='
```